# Downgrade from Core 3 to 2 then Microsoft.AspNetCore.App not recognised

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have VS2019 v16.3.5 installed along with the dotnet core 3 sdk. I can browse to C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and see lots of the versions of the shared framework in folders from 2.1.9 to 3.0.0

**To reproduce the problem:**

- create new console app
- edit project file to add:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

At this point it works ok  but then:

- Change target framework to 2.2

I get the build error:

> The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' was not recognized

Should it be possible to target 2.2 and still use the shared framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FrameworkReference** is a new feature of **ASP.NET Core 3.0**. Not available in the lower versions. For lower versions replace `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` with the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```